# How to stream from a capped collection with Spring data-mongodb-reactive

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I'm trying to use this interesting repository method :

```
@Tailable
Flux<Movie> findWithTailableCursorBy();
```

by expose it in a controller, 
to stream new saved docs in a capped collection:

This is a DataAppInitializr :

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void run(ApplicationReadyEvent evt) {

      operations.collectionExists(Movie.class)
                  .flatMap(exists -> exists ? operations.dropCollection(Movie.class) : Mono.just(exists))
                  .then(operations.createCollection(Movie.class, CollectionOptions.empty()
                             .size(256 * 256)
                             .maxDocuments(10)
                             .capped()))
                  .thenMany(operations.insertAll(Flux.just("Jeyda", "Kaf Efrit").map(title-> new Movie(title)).collectList()))
                  .subscribe();
}
```

This is the controller method :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/tail", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
Flux<Movie> allTail() {
    return movieRepository.findWithTailableCursorBy();
}
```

I got no exception,
I’m just getting a white page in the browser and no stream of new docs. Am I missing a step ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are creating  Movies and querying for Person. what is this? is this correct?

Comment: have you enabled `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories` and are you sure that records are inserted into mongo. Because  I added the documents manually into mongo and your code works.

Comment: No issue with persistence, every thing works well. the data initializer add docs to the capped collection. I can request all docs Flux<Movie> and even when I add this annotation (also boot handle it automaticly by seeing the dep in classpath) I got the same result again.

Comment: @pvpkiran are you seeing the new record emited everytime you add it into mongo ? browser or curl ? thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. Works like a peach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165845/discussion-between-pvpkiran-and-montassar-el-behi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from SecurityWebFilterChain from the spring-security-webflux. I should contact concerned people to notify them. 
Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects in your question that do not fit what you want to achieve:

1. Your code contains blocking bits: `block()`. Do not call `.block()` in initializers and event handlers during startup or when receiving events triggered by reactive infrastructure. Blocking is the easiest way to disrupt any functionality and makes your application defunct.
2. Browsers aren't the ideal tool to consume streams with a page view. Rather use `cURL`.

Besides that, you seem to have a mismatch between `Flux<Person>` and `Flux<Movie>`.

Comment: Hi, I suscribe to it instead. I used to have a Stream.generate() event stream printed one by one on chrome, did the thing well but I'll use curl. sorry again for Flux<Person> I edited it.